# Dokku + docker - wrong ip after autoreset - how to deal with it?

Tags: docker, nginx, dokku

I'm junior dev.

I have a known problem: (https://github.com/dokku/dokku/issues/2602)

Wrong ip used for docker container after auto restart. In nginx config there is still `172.17.0.18:5000` while app after restart has `172.17.0.6:5000`.

command: `dokku nginx:build-config ws -t` fixs the problem but I have no idea how to detect restart of app inside container.

The implementation forces me to use `dokku network:set node-js-app bind-all-interfaces false` - always false, becouse I have few apps/services on the same port, and when i turn on binding to all interfaces everything crashes out.

I made a service that rebuild config when it found in logs that app reseted but in docker events there are no such events ;/

in service file:

`/usr/bin/docker events --filter "service=ws.web" --filter event=restart | /usr/bin/dokku nginx:build-config ws -t`

Any ideas how can I fix it another way? Maybe corn job that will reset config every some time? but it is a kind of hack and I'm not sure if all will work correctly

This is pre production code (few days left)... This is one big project after one year of coding... and now this comes out. So everything is configured and is very delicate.

nginx.conf

```
server {
  listen      [::]:15365;
  listen      15365;

  access_log  /var/log/nginx/web-access.log;
  error_log   /var/log/nginx/web-error.log;

  location    / {

    gzip on;
    gzip_min_length  1100;
    gzip_buffers  4 32k;
    gzip_types    text/css text/javascript text/xml text/plain text/xcomponent application/javascript application/x-javascriptapplication/json application/xml  application/rss+xml font/truetypeapplication/x-font-ttf font/opentype application/vnd.ms-fontobject 
image/svg+xml;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_comp_level  6;

    proxy_pass  http://web-5000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Request-Start $msec;
  }
  include /home/dokku/web/nginx.conf.d/*.conf;

  error_page 400 401 402 403 405 406 407 408 409 410 411 412 413 414 415 416 417 418 420 422 423 424 426 428 429 431 444 449 450 451 /400- error.html;
  location /400-error.html {
    root /var/lib/dokku/data/nginx-vhosts/dokku-errors;
    internal;
  }

  error_page 404 /404-error.html;
  location /404-error.html {
    root /var/lib/dokku/data/nginx-vhosts/dokku-errors;
    internal;
  }

  error_page 500 501 502 503 504 505 506 507 508 509 510 511 /500-error.html;
  location /500-error.html {
    root /var/lib/dokku/data/nginx-vhosts/dokku-errors;
    internal;
  }

}

upstream web-5000 {

  server 172.17.0.18:5000;

  server 172.17.0.19:5000;
}
```

`172.17.0.18:5000;` and `172.17.0.19:5000;` was correct ip's before "app" reset inside the container.

But after the reset they have ips: `172.17.0.6:5000;` and `172.17.0.7:5000;` but nginx didnt notice it, thats becouse I have to use this command: `dokku nginx:build-config ws -t` but I dont know how to detect it. `docker events` is clear.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Can you include the Nginx configuration or any other part of your code in the question?  I can tell you that using the 172.17.0.0/16 Docker-internal IP addresses is basically always wrong; if you start your containers on the same non-default `docker run --net` then their `--name` will be valid hostnames visible to your other containers.

Comment: Done + added more info bout project. Thanks for answer.